# What process deleted the glpi-agent service?

Tags: windows-10, event-log, windows-services

My glpi-agent service was deleted upon my Windows 10 reboot.

I would like to find out what deleted it :

```
C:\> sc.exe query glpi-agent
[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

C:\>
```

I have filtered the System eventlogs with the event ids 5141,7045,4660 but could only find the event corresponding to the creation of that service.

How can I find what process deleted the glpi-agent service ?